# Is there a CI service for bitbucket.org which allow managing build commands in a VCS file?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket

Since travis-ci.org doesn't support bitbucket.org I need another CI service which supports it and allows managing the build commands in a VCS file (like `.travis.yml` in travis).

My quite annoying research result so far is:

- semaphoreci.com: projects which are forks aren't listed even after refreshing the project list
- app.shippable.com: signing up with both github.com and bitbucket.org doesn't work
- codeship.com: doesn't support to run commands as ''root'' user((https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/root-level-access/))
- www.snap-ci.com: no support for bitbucket.org((http://www.slant.co/topics/186/~hosted-continuous-integration-services))

I don't get why people would not want to share the CI service build commands in the VCS - chances of good collaboration without such a feature seems small to me. Even if one adds a script file in the VCS it still needs to be set up in the CI service which appears to be an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few months ago Bitbucket launched [Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-792496469.html). Quoting from the link:

> Continuous delivery is now seamlessly integrated into your Bitbucket Cloud repositories.

You may use it on free plans, but next year they will reduce the build minutes for free plans from 500 minutes to 50 minutes [as told in this link](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing/upcoming?_ga=1.218014672.790415027.1417681798&tab=host-in-the-cloud).

Answer (score 7):

Also, CircleCI is supporting Bitbucket. It has free plan with 1500 build minutes. It can be triggered by commit or tag in BB. https://circleci.com/

Comment: Am I right that the free plan with CircleCI does not allow for private repos on BitBucket?

Comment: That does not seem to be so. We have been using free plan of CircleCI (Linux, 1 node) with only private Bitbucket repos.

Answer (score 1):

The company that owns BitBucket also has a product called [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) for CI. Though most should work with any git that provides a webhook.

Comment: Bamboo is in the process of being deprecated. Atlassian has provided Bitbucket Pipelines as their alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog](https://medium.com/@blcsntb/travis-ci-for-bitbucket-32e776362baf), it is possible to use **Travis-CI for Bitbucket**:

**Clone github repository:**

```
git clone https://github.com/{github_user}/{github_repository}
cd {github_repository}
```

**Add submodule bitbucket repository:**

```
git submodule add https://bitbucket.org/{bitbucket_user}/{bitbucket_repository}
```

**Add .travis.yml to root dir:**

```
git:
  submodules:
    false
before_install:
  - echo -e "machine bitbucket.org\n  login $BITBUCKET_USER_NAME\n  password $BITBUCKET_USER_PASSWORD" >~/.netrc
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
$BITBUCKET_USER_NAME is bitbucket username
$BITBUCKET_USER_PASSWORD is app password
```

Open https://travis-ci.org/{github_user}/{github_repository}

Answer (score 0):

A Semaphore CI user can add a fork of a project to his Semaphore account following these steps on the [documentation page](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/adding-github-bitbucket-project-to-semaphore.html). Also, Semaphore is building a fork pull request and those builds are visible.

Comment: But semaphore doesn't manage an automatically detected build script in the VCS, does it?

Answer (score 0):

There also is (now) an option to use GitLab as CI/CD server for repository hosted on Bitbucket.

See the documentation here: [on GitLab site](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/bitbucket_integration.html)